# References to papers/books that uses a kernel to smooth a discrete distribution

Tags: reference-request, normal-distribution, reference-works

Since a kernel, such as Gaussian, is often used to smooth out the distribution of discrete points in 1D, 2D or 3D, I believe there must be some study materials or research work that have used this, and I need this for references in my work.

I would appreciate if you can point me to any book/research papers/study materials that use a kernel to smooth out some distributions.

Thanks